# Need to capture database name when error occurs with sp_msforeachdb

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am running a dynamic sql command with sp_msforeachdb for each database. However the command bombs for a certain database.

How is '?' used to display the database name when the error happens? I tried using it in a Catch statement but my syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Just use DB_NAME()

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'USE ? SELECT DB_NAME() ...do stuff'
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked to me:

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb 'select *, print ''?'' from TABLE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the script, you get for all db's the ouput "master" with *DB_NAME()*. 
You can use *DB_NAME(DB_ID(''?''))* in these cases:

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'select DB_NAME(DB_ID(''?'')), Value from ?.dbo.MyTable WHERE(ColumnX = N''1'')'
```

which would result in something like this:

+-------------+-------+
| DBLegacy    | VA1 |
+-------------+-------+
+-------------+-------+
| DBNew12       | ABC      |
+-------------+-------+
+-------------+-------+
| DBOld333 | XYZ      |
+-------------+-------+

To get the results into one result set see:
[SQL Server: sp_MSforeachdb into single result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544351/sql-server-sp-msforeachdb-into-single-result-set) 
This would result in this:

+-------------+-------+
| DBLegacy    | VA1 |
+-------------+-------+
| DBNew12       | ABC      |
+-------------+-------+
| DBOld333 | XYZ      |
+-------------+-------+