# SQL Server: sp_MSforeachdb into single result set

Tags: sql-server

I am going to archive to get a query which pulls some data from all databases and return a single result set.

Right now I have the following:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(4000)
SELECT @command = '
USE [?] 
SELECT 
    database_name = DB_NAME(database_id)
    , log_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = "LOG" THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , row_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = "ROWS" THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , total_size_mb = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , Kostenstelle = (select value from sys.extended_properties WHERE name =     "Kostenstelle")
FROM sys.master_files WITH(NOWAIT)
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
GROUP BY database_id
'
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

The code above will return in multiple result sets.

The result should look like the following:

```
|database_name|log_size_mb|row_size_mb|Kostenstelle|
+-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|demoA        |         12|         10|        xxxx|
|demoB        |         52|         12|        xxxx|
```

Answer (score 12):

Got a reply from a colleague - 1000 thanks

```
DECLARE @command varchar(4000)
SELECT @command = '
USE [?] 
SELECT 
database_name = CAST(DB_NAME(database_id) AS VARCHAR(50))
, log_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = "LOG" THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
, row_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = "ROWS" THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
, total_size_mb = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
, Kostenstelle = CAST((select value from sys.extended_properties WHERE     name =     "Kostenstelle") AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM sys.master_files WITH(NOWAIT)
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
GROUP BY database_id
'

DECLARE @DatabasesKst TABLE
(
  database_name VARCHAR(50),
  log_size_mb DECIMAL(8,2),
  row_size_mb DECIMAL(8,2),
  total_size DECIMAL(8,2),
  Kostenstelle VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT  INTO @DatabasesKst
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command

select * from @DatabasesKst
```

..

If you want to filter out some of the databases, you can wrap the 'USE [?]' with an IF/BEGIN/END like this.

```
DECLARE @command varchar(4000)
SELECT @command = '
IF ''?'' NOT IN(''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'') 
BEGIN 
    USE [?]


    SELECT 
     (your select/from/where statement here)


 END
'
```

Comment: Thanks to you and your colleague.  The "trick" here is to have the scope of the @variableTable outside of dynamic-sql.  Well played!

Answer (score 3):

You can create table in some db and save results in this table if you add `INSERT` statement in your query :

```
DECLARE @command varchar(4000)
SELECT @command = '
USE [?] 
INSERT INTO <DbName>.<SchemaName>.<TableName>
SELECT 
database_name = DB_NAME(database_id)
...
```

Comment: well, yes that will be possible but my wish is to not use a table if possible. I also tried to create a temp table in memory with declare @mytable table ... but it was not working for me because the "mytable is not available inside the ms_foreachdb loop :-(