# Find particular column in particular table in all databases at the same time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have many identical databases and I would like to find all databases that have particular entry in the same table.

This is what I have to run agains each databse to get the info I need:

```
select OrderID, OrderRef 
from Orders 
where OrderID = '12345'
```

I thought that I can run my query against all databses using unsupported `sp_MSforeachdb`, but I'm not desperate to use this particular method.

```
CREATE TABLE ##tmpTable(OrderID VARCHAR(MAX), OrderRef VARCHAR(MAX));

DECLARE @command varchar(1000)

SELECT 
    @command =  'Use ? INSERT INTO ##tmpTable SELECT ''[?]'', OrderID, OrderRef FROM Orders WHERE OrderID = ''12345'';'
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command

SELECT * FROM ##tmpTable;
GO

DROP TABLE ##tmpTable;
```

When I run it as it is I am getting following error:

> Column name or number of supplied
>   values does not match table definition.

Additionally, it doesn't show which database the results come from. What I would like to get is this:

```
DatabaseName | OrderID | OrderRef
```

Comment: What you mean doesnt work? because if work but you need the name check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808338/need-to-capture-database-name-when-error-occurs-with-sp-msforeachdb

Comment: To me it worked as expected.

Comment: I updated my question to explain which part doesn't work.

Comment: Put 2 single quotes around 12345. ''12345''.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm left with the "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Comment: Add database name to the temp table. You are inserting 3 columns into a 2 column table.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your comments I was able to modify my query and it works now:

```
CREATE TABLE ##tmpTable(DB_Name VARCHAR(MAX), OrderID VARCHAR(MAX), OrderRef VARCHAR(MAX));

DECLARE @command varchar(1000)
SELECT @command =  'Use ? INSERT INTO ##tmpTable select ''?'', OrderID, OrderRef from Orders WHERE OrderID = ''12345''
;'
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command

SELECT * FROM ##tmpTable;
GO
DROP TABLE ##tmpTable;
```